# Writing a S3 object with GrantRead giving 400

Tags: go, amazon-s3

My service uses AWS S3 go sdk to upload an object into aws account say **ACT1**, I want to grant read permission to a different subaccount **ACT2** so that it can read the object upon successful upload. This is how the code looks like

```
var canonicalIDOfSubAccount = "abcd09kialjf1124"

 // Upload attempts to upload a file at a particular key.
 func (s *client) Upload(ctx context.Context, bucket, key string, body io.Reader) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            logging.Error("s3", "panic recovered. err: %v", r)
        }
    }()

    params := &s3manager.UploadInput{
         Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
         Key:    aws.String(key),
         Body:   body,
         GrantRead: aws.String(canonicalIDOfSubAccount),
    }

    // Perform an upload.
    _, err = s.uploader.UploadWithContext(ctx, params)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error is ", err.Error(), err)
    }
    return
}
```

On execution, aws is throwing the error 
`InvalidArgument: Argument format not recognized status 400`

Without the GrantRead, the upload works well, but the object is not readable by the **ACT2**.

On checking with AWS support, they said that providing the canonical id is the right value for the header GrantRead.

Comment: Are you sure the canonical id has a format like that: `79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be`

Comment: It's just a random string i put here to represent canonical id in the code above. checked with the subaccount admin about the read canonical id being provided in service code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the way to use this properly:

When providing canonical id, the correct way is:

```
params := &s3manager.UploadInput{
     Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
     Key:    aws.String(key),
     Body:   body,
     GrantRead: aws.String("id=" + canonicalIDOfSubAccount),
}
```